# Fetching with a body vs fetching without a body (react, express)

Tags: reactjs, express, async-await, fetch

I am new to web dev and am having some issues making a fetch request with a json body attached. Right now, if I make a fetch call without a body, the fetch connects to my api (which logs that it has been connected to), retrieves values from my database, and sends them back up to the front end without issue. However, when I add a body object as the second parameter to my fetch request, my fetch never connects to the api. No error is outputted, it just waits, and my api never logs that it has been connected to.

Here is the code. This works:

```
//this.props.chosenInterests is an object
    async sample(){
        //url-friendly string
        const university = this.props.chosenUniversity.replace(/\s/, '+');

        const query = '/interest/' + university;

        try{
            const response = await fetch(query, {});
            if(response.ok){
                const jsonResponse = await response.json();
                globalVar = jsonResponse;

                this.forceUpdate();
            }
            else{
                throw new Error('Request Failed!');
            }
        }
        catch (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

while this does not:

```
//this.props.chosenInterests is an object
    async sample(){
        //url-friendly string
        const university = this.props.chosenUniversity.replace(/\s/, '+');

        const query = '/interest/' + university;

        try{
            const response = await fetch(query, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(this.props.chosenInterests)
            });
            if(response.ok){
                const jsonResponse = await response.json();
                globalVar = jsonResponse;

                this.forceUpdate();
            }
            else{
                throw new Error('Request Failed!');
            }
        }
        catch (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Here is my api:

```
//already mounted router at /interest
interestRouter.get('/:university', (req, res, next) => {
    const university = req.params.university.replace(/\+/g, ' ');

    console.log('Connected.');

    db.all('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Table.university = $university', {$university : university},
        (error, result) => {
            if(error){
                next(error);
            }
            else{
                res.json(result);
            }
        }
    )
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm just confused as to why I'm not getting an error or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the POST fails is because your express script is looking for a GET, not a POST. If you change it to the following:

```
interestRouter.post('/:university', (req, res, next) => {...
```

Then you can see the body of the POST in req.body.